# Show hidden folders and files on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-distributions, nautilus

I'm in the middle of a migration from Ubuntu to Fedora. How do I make Nautilis in Fedora show the hidden files and folders (those with a dot)? It's Nautilus 3.8.2, if I go to Preferences and choose "show hidden and backup files", they keep getting ignored.

Comment: I just found out I can press CTRL+H to show hidden files. It is a non-satisfactory workaround, as I have to press it every time I open a new window.

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal and type:

```
 dconf-editor
```

Enter and then:

**org -> gtk -> settings -> file-chooser**

mark **show-hidden**

Comment: @fixer1234- install **dconf-editor** then navigate to **org ->gtk->settings->file-chooser** through **dconf-edtor**, then in the **file-chooser** mark the **show-hidden** checkbox

Comment: Sadly, this does not appear to work as of Fedora 29. I tried setting it, nothing happened. Tried re-starting as well. The option sticks in dconf-editor, but it doesn't appear to do anything. However, control+H does work to toggle showing hidden files.